# is it possible to see content of Documents folder on iphone from debugger console

Tags: iphone

I want to see the content of Documents folder from console, I can see for simulator but it's not working for device

my path is **/var/mobile/Applications/3E79C7B3-2639-477F-B355-1A3C70D4ECBE/Documents**
but how to check this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get the location of the Documents directory like so:

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
path = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
```

And then simply print the contents of the directory to the console:

```
NSLog(@"%@", [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:path error:nil]);
```

Here's the relevant documentation: http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/LowLevelFileMgmt/Articles/StandardDirectories.html

Comment: i mean so we cant see the hard copy of file as we can see for simulator??

Comment: hey in simulator i can see icell,
    list,
    "sample1.cfg"    but on iphone i can see only icell .. so is something wrong???

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. You mean there are files missing from the Documents folder on your device? And what do you mean by "see the hard copy of the file"? You can't actually get to the file in the Finder as you can with the simulator,  if that's what you mean.

Comment: yes i was thinking of that only point is i want to trace the path and pull data from path but simulator and iphone they hav different path so which path i choose to open file from document folder??

Comment: Are you trying to access files inside your Documents folder? It sounds like you're trying to hard code the path to the Documents folder. Don't do that, use NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains as shown above.